# Boton Editar en CRUD

Tags: variables, laravel-blade

Estoy en laravel 6.0 con windows y quiero editar un registro de computadoras de un listado de computadoras que tengo, pero cuando presiono el boton editar me poner el siguiente error:

> Argument 2 passed to 
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse::__construct() must be of the type integer, array given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector.php on line 203

En la vista donde tengo el listado de computadora tengo implementado lo siguiente:

```
 <td>
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{url('/computadoras/'.$computadora>id.'/edit')}}">
    Editar
    </a>
 </td>
```

En mi controlador tengo implementado :

```
 public function edit($id) {
    $computadoras= Computadora::findOrFail($id);
    return redirect('computadoras/computadorasedit',compact('computadoras'));
 }
```

En mi archivo de rutas tengo:

```
Route::get('/computadoras/{id}/edit', 'ComputadorasController@edit');
```

En la vista donde va a estar el formulario editar:
tengo simplemente un texto para ver si cuando presiono el boton editar se dirige hacia la vista de editar pero me encuentro con el error antes descrito.Cualquier opinion seri de mucha ayuda

Comment: Al generar la url, ¿no debería ser $computadora->id?

Comment: ya lo arregle pero sigue igual

Comment: Podrías actualizar la pregunta con la modificación que hiciste en la ruta.

Comment: <td>
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{url('/computadoras/'.$computadora->id.'/edit')}}">
    Editar
    </a>
 </td>

Answer (score 0):

**Prueba dos cosa:**

**PRIMERO:**

cambia el metodo edit() del controlador por este:

```
 public function edit($id) {
    $computadoras= Computadora::findOrFail($id);
    return view('computadoras/computadorasedit')->with(compact('computadoras'));
 }
```

El `redirect()` se usa mas en el store() y update() cuando se quiere retornar a un direccion que se ha llamado antes por medio del formulario.

SEGUNDO:

prueba si la ruta esta funcionando correctamente poniendo un `dd()` en lugar de  ir a la ruta, es para confirmar que: a) que se esta enviando bien la ruta, b) que el modelo esta configurado con el controlador y puede hacer la consulta.

pon este codigo de prueba:

```
 public function edit($id) {
    $computadoras= Computadora::findOrFail($id);
    dd($computadoras);
 }
```

y lo pruebas...